# Replace a specific character in a string

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I replace the 12th character of a string if it's equal to 'X'
For example if I have 'ABXD1X354XJXOKJX'; in this case I will replace the 'X' in the 12th position with 'Y'. result : 'ABXD1X354XJYOKJX'

I was thinking to use regexp_replace function to point the 12th character, test if it's equal to 'X', if yes replace it with 'Y' but it's more complicated than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without knowing more of how are constituted your string, this should work:

```
-- matches:
select regexp_replace('12dasdf32432Xasdasd', '([[:alnum:]]{11})(X{1})', '\1Y' ) from dual
union
-- doesn't match:
select regexp_replace('12dasdf32432Zasdasd', '([[:alnum:]]{11})(X{1})', '\1Y' ) from dual
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for, the string is alphanumeric

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you using `SUBSTR`:

```
select 
  substr('ABXD1X354XJXOKJX', 1, 11) ||
  case when substr('ABXD1X354XJXOKJX', 12, 1) = 'X' THEN 'Y' ELSE substr('ABXD1X354XJXOKJX', 12, 1) END ||
  substr('ABXD1X354XJXOKJX', 13)
from dual
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10407)

Comment: Thanks that worked ! I thought there was a way to replace directly the 12th character without having to concatenate

Comment: @DJozef -- np, glad I could help!  This can be accomplished with regexp_replace, but I think this is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
  CASE SUBSTR(yourfield, 12, 1) WHEN 'X' THEN 'Y' END
```

and add in concatenation as necessary

Answer (score 0):

For this, it may be just as easy to use the SUBSTR function.

Example, if UPPER(SUBSTR('ABXD1X354XJYOKJX', 12, 1)) = 'X'